# Synology NAS, direct copy/move from USB card reader?

Tags: synology

I'd like to be able to plug in an SD card reader direct to my DS415play and be able to move files to my photos location so that i dont have to do it at a slower rate from my laptop over wifi.

I've enabled to usb drive in 'external devices' in the control panel but it appears that the NAS will not read the format of the card. The card was formatted using default options on a Windows 7 machine. The sandisk micro sd card is used without problem in a GoPro camera. The card can be read fine from windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the formatting of the SD card. (If Windows and the GoPro can read it, the Syno should be able too.)

The card-reader itself is most likely not supported by the Operating System on the Synology.
This USB interface will take an USB stick or USB harddrive without any problems, but a card-reader (especially the multi-slot ones that take different types of cards) can be a subtly different type of device. Not all of them are supported...

This is a known issue with Synology devices. Some card-readers just don't work, while other brands/models work just fine.

The Synology support web-site and the forums have several posts about this. You may read up on those for further information.

Upgrading DSM (the software that forms the operating system inside the Syno) may fix the problem, as Synology may have improved the card-reader support in newer versions.
If you are already on the latest version of DSM, you can try another card-reader to see if that gives better results.
If your Wifi is really slow making a copy of the SD-card to a USB stick on your laptop and then putting the USB stick in the Syno may actually be faster than copying over the Wifi. Worth a try if all else fails.

Comment: It was able to read the capacity of the inserted card, but complained about the format. Does that still fit with a driver issue? I'll try to get a screen-grab if i can.

Comment: @PaulGeorge Yes. That is one of the possible variants. Multiple people in the Synology forums report exactly the same thing.

Comment: This is not true. If the card is formatted exFAT, you will not be able to read it unless you install the exFAT compatibility app from the Synology app center.

Answer (score 0):

If the NAS "sees" the card but won't let you browse it in the file manager, most likely the card has been formatted with the exFAT file system.

You have two options:

1. Reformat the card as FAT32, or
2. In the Synology Package Center, purchase the "exFAT Access" app (you pay a nominal fee for this because Synology has to pay a per-unit license fee for exFAT).